# Can you update redis in place while redis is running without causing any downtime?

Tags: redis

I have some redis instances running on Ubuntu servers. Is it possible to update the version of redis installed on those servers from 3.2.9 to 3.2.13 (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antirez/redis/3.2/00-RELEASENOTES) without causing any downtime for users? Users currently interact with the redis instances running on the servers through a proxy.

Comment: Do you have master-replica set?

Comment: Yes, I have a master slave setup using 3 redis [sentinels](https://redis.io/topics/sentinel)

Comment: So all you have to do is upgrade the slave and then upgrade the master